# QGIS doesn't show datapoints of .csv file

Tags: layers, coordinates, gps, excel

I am not yet familiar with QGIS and I am trying to add an Excel file with GPS points and data (add layer > add delimited text layer). The Excel shows up as a layer, but the points do not show on the map and there is no option to "Zoom to Layer" when right clicking on the layer. It doesn't seem to be problem with the Excel itself, because when another person tried to upload the file in his QGIS, it did show the data and points, but he also didn't know why it worked for him, but not for me.

What could I be doing wrong?

I have added screenshots of the settings before adding the excel (I tried different settings). I don't know if the following is relevant, but when adding the excel it also doesn't prefill the X and Y field in the settings (which seemed to happen automatically for the person that did get to see the points), so I selected the x and y manually. I have also added a screenshot of the setting of the overall project.

[image: project properties]

[image: delimited text options]

[image: layers]

Answer (score 1):

Tick the box “decimal separator is comma”

Answer (score 0):

Replace commas (,) with dots (.) in the csv file. Or QGIS can misinterpret the coordinates as text and not decimal numbers.